# MySQL: How to check if a field value exists in a comma separated field in the same table

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, mysql-workbench

I have  a table that contains two string values. The second column `col2` contains a series of a comma separated strings. The following is a simple example:

```
col1            | col2
--------------------------------------------------------
aaa:123.456     | aaa:123.456/,aaa:000.123.456/
```

I want to retrieve the rows where if I added `000.` after `aaa:` to `col1`, it matches any of the series of strings (comma separated strings) in `col2`. Note that `col2` strings may contains `/` at the end which needs to be considered in the query.

I tried this query using `IN` clause:

```
select *
from table 
where concat('aaa:000',substring_index(col1,'aaa:',-1)) IN (concat(col2,'/'))
```

I expect my query matches the row. But it does not. Why? Isn't IN supposed to check every element in the comma separated strings  in `col2`? If not, can you help me with a query that return the row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with this:

```
select *
from tablename 
where 
  concat(',', col2, ',') like
  concat('%,aaa:000.', substring_index(col1,'aaa:',-1), '/,%')
```

and if there may or may not be a `/` at the end then:

```
select *
from tablename 
where 
  concat(',', col2, ',') like
  concat('%,aaa:000.', substring_index(col1,'aaa:',-1), '/,%')
  or
  concat(',', col2, ',') like
  concat('%,aaa:000.', substring_index(col1,'aaa:',-1), ',%')
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9xk5VzoWvfY5zqVQom4a4/0)

Comment: Why do you always assume the matching in col2 always proceeded by a comma? it can be the first item, where no proceeding comma, can be in the middle, where it is proceeding and followed by a comma, and can be the last item where it is proceeding by a comma but not followed by one.

Comment: I don't assume that the matching in col2 always proceeded by a comma. This is why I concatenate `,` at the start and at the end of both patterns so that I take care of any case.

Comment: If I search for c in a,b,c,d then I do this:  `',a,b,c,d,' like '%,c,%'`